# Removing Button From Section 0 in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview that contains 4 sections. In sections 2,3,and 4 I want to have a + button to add information to a "Saved" array. I have the logic setup for adding information, but I'm having issues with the tableview cells.

I don't want the + button to appear in section 0, since that's where we're adding the data. Here's my cellForRowAt method...

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! SchoolTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        cell.addFavoritesButton.removeFromSuperview()
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = Items.sharedInstance.elementaryList[indexPath.row]
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = Items.sharedInstance.intermediateList[indexPath.row]
    } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = Items.sharedInstance.highschoolList[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
```

This works great at first! But if I scroll down, more and more cells will remove the button. It's not limiting it to section 0 because of reusable cells.

Can anyone think of a better way to remove this button for the first section only?

[Screenshot of section 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwjTe.png)

[Screenshot of section 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksJ42.png)

Comment: because you're reusing a cell that has done `cell.addFavoritesButton.removeFromSuperview()`. so when it's reused... * __poof__ * bye bye forever sweet sweet `addFavoritesButton`, don't care which section you're in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run show the cells correctly because of all cells are new instances of the cell class (without reusing) , but after scroll shown cells may be reused with a possibility that this reused cell be the one in section zero which you removed the button from it ,  You can try to show/hide it

```
 if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
    cell.addFavoritesButton.isHidden = true
} 
else
{
   cell.addFavoritesButton.isHidden = false
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried hiding the button, but I never made sure to unhide it for other sections. Two hours wasted, but I won't be making that mistake again!

Comment: yes , keep this logic in mind as always you don't know whether it was a cell with shown/hidden button

Comment: @DustinJohnson , it will also work with **cell.addFavoritesButton.isHidden = (indexPath.section == 0)**  out of any if statement

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting that cells are reused. You need to deal, every time thru `cellForRowAt`, with the possibility that this cell already has the button from a previous use and should not have it in this use, or with the possibility that it lacks the button and needs it in this use.

For example, you cannot assume that just because the section is `1`, the cell has the button, because it might have been used in section `0` earlier and lacks the button now. You need, in that case, to *add* it. But you are not doing that.

Thus, for *every* branch of your logic, you must be explicit about whether to add or remove the button. If you are really going to add and remove it, that can get complicated. You would need to keep a copy of the button somewhere, so you can add it. You'd make sure you don't add it twice to the same cell. You'd make sure you don't try to remove it if it is already removed.

As has been suggested in another answer, the simpler way to deal with this is not to add and remove at all, but to make *visibility* of the button dependent on whether this section is `0`:

```
// do this in _every_ case
cell.addFavoritesButton.isHidden = (indexPath.section == 0)
```

That's a single line of code that does, much better, the thing you are trying to do.

Comment: As usual your answer is clear and to-the-point. (voted.) I was going to recommend setting the isHidden state also, but you beat me to it.

Comment: this code will show button in section zero instead of hide it should be **indexPath.section == 0**

Comment: @Sh_Khan Thanks I'll fix that

Answer (score 1):

Once you remove the button from the cell by calling `cell.addFavoritesButton.removeFromSuperview()`, it would not be added back again for you when the cell is reused. You should keep the button on the cell, but hide it with

```
cell.addFavoritesButton.isHidden = indexPath.section == 0
```

or add a new feature that lets end-users remove items from section zero, and change the picture on the button from `+` to `-`:

[image]

Comment: Hiding the button was definitely the smarter move. However it still removed it in lower sections. Sh_Khan had a really simple solution that re-added it for other sections.

Comment: @DustinJohnson My solution (a single line outside of any `if`s) will hide and un-hide the button as necessary.

Comment: This answer also will toggle the hide/show as necessary in one line of code , but i preferred to show the logic according to question , so OP can get the idea